Peugeot 2008 turns off mid-drive and burns huge amounts of oil. What could be the reasons and how to fix?
My Mom bought a used 2017, Peugot 2008 1.2 puretech turbo Gasoline/Benzine Automatic car,
When she drove it before buying she said it drove well, 2 days later the car started to shutdown mid-drive when on low RPM's mostly.
The car burns large amounts of oil, and Turbo was changed recently to a new one by previous owner.
I took it to my regular mechanic, he said it was good, needed a maintenance.
Changed engine oil, oil filter, air filter, front brake pads and cooling liquid.
But it still turns off mid-drive, and consumes lots of oil.  I went to Peugeot Garage here, and bought spark plugs and new oil cover cap (first one was bad)
After changing these it ran a little bit better (replaced spark plugs in a Peugeot Specialist Mechanic, He Said engine is weak, but still I would like it to run without turning off even if engine is weak)
He checked the Engine codes and they were the following :

So I did some investigating on the internet and asked a guy who works at Peugeot, he told me that I need to do a carbon clean for the engine. I added a bottle of Lucas fuel treatment and Lucas oil additive but still didn't add it with a new batch of oil, although I changed the oil 1 month ago.
After clouds of black smoke coming out of the car, resetting the error codes and checking again found the following errors.

But I had recently changed the spark plugs to new expensive ones from Peugeot,
the guy who did the carbon clean with this big machine and pipes told me it could be the coil on Cylinder 1, its a 3 Cylinder car, I ordered another expensive part (Original Coil and Crankshaft position sensor) as well.
The car rides a little rough as well, drives like a manual I would say, Not like an automatic Transmission.
What do you think the problem could be, any other suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! \

Was a compression test done? Did the mechanic check the timing system, either belt or chain, for alignment and tension etc?

What was the status of the oil? When the mechanic drained, was the sump down to... 1L of oil... or less? Was there sludge? Metal shavings? If it were me I'd be trying to get rid of this car.

@AdamO thanks for the comment,
yes thats we are trying to do, we are trying to make it run for at least 10 minutes without shutting down so we can get rid of it.
the oil looked good, no shavings and it wasn't black. and we kept adding oil each time it dropped, no compression test was done, and no alignment or tension checks for the engine as well,
do you think we need to do those checks ?
maybe rocker head gasket could help as well ?
thanks a lot

@MajdMahajenah is scrapping the car an option? You can try selling parts yourself. My experience with a turbo running chronically low oil is that the engine is all but grenaded, needs a whole rebuild. Massive carbon buildup on poppet valves (these need walnut blasting, not potions like Lucas additive), this is my most likely guess about low power. A compression test would objectively tell you that the power is low irrespective of "spark" . I doubt it's the coil pack.

@AdamO sadly scraping is not an option here where i live. Cars are just too expensive.
I totally understand what you are saying and appreciate the help and response. What do you think could be like a temp fix. To make it run maybe for 2 week or a month. Just so i will be able to trade it in to a new one at the dealers.
Also did a carbon cleaning with carbon cleaning machine cost me around 200 usd.
And tomorrow im getting the cranckshaft position sensor and the new coil.  Will update on how things look after i install them   Thanks again

@AdamO
so what i did was
change the cranckshaft position sensor and the new coil.
cleaned in throttle intake body, cleaned the lambda sensor, cleaned the map sensor, did an engine flush. also cleaned the idle control valve.
removed old oil and filter ( although they are one month old )
added a new oil with oil stabilizer and new oil filter, disconnected the - battery side for half an hour. but its still having the symptoms. sadly. its goes into limp mode after a short while.
could it be the ecu ? maybe needs reprogramming ?
thanks a lot. appreciate all the help

@MajdMahajenah this is out of my expertise, but I replaced a header on my motorcycle and swapped the lambda sensor. This trigged a fault that caused me to enter limp mode each time. Getting into a shop with software to reset and recheck codes is a good idea.

@AdamO sounds great thanks. will try that.
